# SpreeCommerce Filter by total_on_hand

Tags: spree

I have a spree commerce search like this:

`build_searcher(:taxon => @category.id)`

and I would like to exclude all products that are out of stock (as far as I understand `total_at_hand==0` for these products, but `total_at_hand` is not a column).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I have found this ` Spree::Product.
  includes(:variants_including_master => :stock_items).
  where("spree_stock_items.count_on_hand > 0”).
  references(:spree_stock_items)` have you tried this

Comment: @Arv Nice, works beautifully. I am using `build_searcher(:taxon => @category.id).retrieve_products.includes(:variants_including_master => :stock_items).where('spree_stock_items.count_on_hand > 0').references(:spree_stock_items)` now. I wonder, however, if this is a good (clean) way to do this or whether I should define a ProductFitlter or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have found this `Spree::Product. includes(:variants_including_master => :stock_items). where("spree_stock_items.count_on_hand > 0”). references(:spree_stock_items)` have you tried this